# Material not showing texture data

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing, materials

I wanted to create a new material using an image texture.

It worked fine, but then it suddenly turned purple.

Is there any switch that I might have accidentally turned on that causes this behavior?

[image: screen shot of blender]

Comment: @RayMairlot  Ah, yes, thank you very much! Should I delete my post?

Comment: No, there's no problem with duplicates existing, they will all direct people to the original question.